# Streaming through a list of java objects and break if a condition is meet

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a question about streaming through a list of java objects and break if a condition is meet,

I have an entity City like below

```
@Entity
public class City {

private Country country;
private ClosestCity closestCity;
private NearestCity nearestCity;
private SisterCity sisterCity;

}
```

ClosestCity, NearestCity and SisterCity are city with foreign keys in the entity city.
I have a list of doctors that are situated in the different cities and I want to allocate a patient to doctor who's city is closest to that of a patient, else allocate to the nearest city, else allocate to the sister city else if none of the above questions are not meet , put the patient to a waiting list.
Below is my method to allocate and its not working.

```
public boolean allocateDoctorToPatient(Patient patient) {

    Practitioner closestPractitioner = null;
    List<Practitioner> practitioners = practitionerService.findAll().get();
    for (Practitioner p : practitioners) {
        //same city
        if (closestPractitioner != null) {
            for (Practitioner p1 : practitioners) {

                if (patient.getCity().equals(p1.getCity())) {
                    closestPractitioner = p1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //loops to find closest city
         else if (closestPractitioner == null) {
            for (Practitioner p2 : practitioners) {

                if (patient.getCity().equals(p2.getCity().getClosestCity())) {
                    closestPractitioner = p2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //loops to find nearest city
        else if (closestPractitioner == null) {
            for (Practitioner p3 : practitioners) {

                if (patient.getCity().equals(p3.getCity().getNearestCity())) {
                    closestPractitioner = p3;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //loops to find sister city
        else if(closestPractitioner == null) {
            for (Practitioner p4 : practitioners) {

                if (patient.getCity().equals(p4.getCity().getSisterCity())) {
                    closestPractitioner = p4;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }



}
   if (closestPractitioner != null) {
        Allocate allocate =new Allocate();

        allocate.setPatient(patient);
        allocate.setPractitioner(closestPractitioner)
        save(allocate);

    }
    else {
       WaitingList waitingList=new WaitingList();
       waitingList.setPatient(patient);
       waitingListService.save(waitingList);
   }

    return closestPractitioner != null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Don't you think that the question is just find the closest city that has a doctor to the patients's city? If thats the case, nearest city, sister city and waiting list makes no sense...unless I am missing something

Comment: Create a separate method to find the closest practitioner, use `return` instead of `break` and get rid of the `if` branching completely

Comment: if i create separate methods, how do i then call the different methods in my controller

Answer (score 0):

Try to use algorithm:

1. Get list of cities which are accapteble for patient.
2. Get list of Practitioner entities which are located in cities from step 1( use HQL or criteria API)
3. Chose closest Practitioner to patient.